# Lubuntu on Usb Flash Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, lubuntu

I'm trying to make a usb that has Lubuntu installed in it, not just a "try without installing". The partition manager isn't able to create a partition in the usb i'm using and installing it on another usb leads to it being without a bootloader. I tried copying all my root files into a usb but my Lubuntu VM keeps saying it's 0%, However when i look in the drive it has folders like "boot" and "cdrom". There doesn't seem to be a way to eject files from Vmware either. How else can you install Ubuntu onto a flash drive.

Comment: You are doing this via Vmware. Are you intending to boot real computers or virtual machines? An alternative is to clone from a [compressed] image file to the pendrive as described in the following link,  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS

Answer (score 1):

Installing to USB is very similar to a normal installation, with a few quirks in partitioning. Also note, this installation will likely take longer and your device will probably have a short lifespan as flash storage devices have limited write cycles, which will quickly be used by the installation.

1. However when it asks about partitioning, click "something else" to manually partition the OS.
2. Find and select your device from the list of devices, you may have to scroll. It should be of the form `/dev/sdX`. (if unsure which device is yours step 6 has a list with device names)
3. Click "new partition table" to wipe any contents/partitions on the device.
4. Click on the "free space" (`/dev/sdX1`)
5. Click "+" to add a new partition.

   - make it a primary partition
   - make it the maximum size
   - set the file system to ext4
   - make sure to check the "format" box
   - set the mountpoint to "/"
   - click "ok"
6. set the device for bootloader installation to your device.
7. continue with installation as usual.